# App forced to stop

Tags: android

I made a new app to check SSID. The code are fine, but when I run on emulation and try to run the app he stop work. Any idea? Sorry for my english.

Here is my log:

```
03-11 15:45:22.580: D/AndroidRuntime(867): Shutting down VM
03-11 15:45:22.580: W/dalvikvm(867): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a45ba8)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867): Process: com.example.wifiscanner, PID: 867
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wifiscanner/com.example.wifiscanner.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.wifiscanner.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.wifiscanner-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.wifiscanner-2, /system/lib]]
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.wifiscanner.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.wifiscanner-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.wifiscanner-2, /system/lib]]
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
03-11 15:45:22.590: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  ... 11 more
03-11 15:45:25.940: I/Process(867): Sending signal. PID: 867 SIG: 9
```

And I changed my activy for ClassHeader.java and i'm using Eclipse.

I fixed the problem. I renamed and made a change in code:

```
package com.example.wifiscanner;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


public void getWifiInfo( Context ctxt  ) {
     int speed = 0;
     String ssid = null;
     String bssid = null; 
     String mac = "00:00:00:00:00:00";
     String netmask = "255.255.255.255";
     String gateway = "0.0.0.0";
     WifiInfo info;
     WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);{

    if (wifi != null) {
        info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        speed = info.getLinkSpeed();
        ssid = info.getSSID();
        bssid = info.getBSSID();
        mac = info.getMacAddress();
        gateway = getSigned( wifi.getDhcpInfo().gateway );
        netmask = getSigned( wifi.getDhcpInfo().netmask );

        System.out.println( "Speed : " + speed
                         + "ssid : "  + ssid 
                          + "bssid :"  + bssid 
                         + "macAddress :"  + mac
                         + "netmaskIp :" + netmask
                         + "gatewayIp :" + gateway  );
     }else{
        System.out.println( "Wi-fi is Null");
     }
  }
}

    public static String getSigned(int  ips ) {
        String ip = "";
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            ip = ips + (( ips >> k * 8) & 0xFF) + ".";
            }
        return ip.substring(0, ip.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

Now I can run the app on emulator, but it's don't show button and nothing. Just a white screen. Any idea? And tks for the help! and sorry again...

Comment: I wish people would read these logs before blindly posting them. This could be a clue: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.wifiscanner.MainActivity"`

Comment: @HoboSapiens while I agree with your statement, it's not the best way to welcome a new user to the site.

Comment: Yes. That error could happen because the class is not in the APK or because Proguard renamed it. If this was a debug build, then presumably that didn't use Proguard.

Comment: I think that the problem is here  `I changed my activy for ClassHeader.java` What do you change and how do you change? Could you post your code - Manifest, YourActivity class, method which you use to start new Activity

Comment: I put the name back and do some changes in code. But now, when I run the app it's just show a white screen, maybe it's in my layout? ou something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing to refer to it as an `Activity` and it's standart methods.

```
public class ClassHeader extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_xml);
    }
}
```

Please take some time to read about the Activity Lifecycle Principles, they're extremely important before you begin programming on Android.

[image]

> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html